# get JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject when parsing a JSON response

Tags: java, android, json

I have developed an Android application that requests places coordinates from a server which responds in JSON format(for the moment it just sends two places):

this is the php code from the server:

```
$place = $db->getCoordinates($name);
if ($place != false) {

     $response[1]["success"] = 1;
     $response[1]["place"]["H"] = $place[1]["H"];
     $response[1]["place"]["V"] = $place[1]["V"];
     $response[1]["place"]["placeid"] = $place[1]["placeid"];
     $response[1]["place"]["name"] = $place[1]["name"];
     $response[1]["place"]["type"] = $place[1]["type"];
     $response[1]["place"]["note"] = $place[1]["note"];
     // place found
     // echo json with success = 1
     $response[2]["success"] = 1;
     $response[2]["place"]["H"] = $place[2]["H"];
     $response[2]["place"]["V"] = $place[2]["V"];
     $response[2]["place"]["placeid"] = $place[2]["placeid"];
     $response[2]["place"]["name"] = $place[2]["name"];
     $response[2]["place"]["type"] = $place[2]["type"];
     $response[2]["place"]["note"] = $place[2]["note"];
     echo json_encode($response);
}
```

When the app get the coordinates it try to parse them this way:

```
            JSONObject json_places = userFunction.getPlaces();
            JSONObject  places = json_places.getJSONObject("1");
            JSONObject  coord = places.getJSONObject("place");
```

getplaces():

```
public JSONObject getPlaces(){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", allcoordinates_tag));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+ip+placesURL, params);
    // return json
    Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}
```

JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 9000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 9000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and here is the JSON with the error:

[image: debug from eclipse]

when the App tries to parse the JSON response it crashes and sends a JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
how can i solve this? 
THANKS

Comment: What is JSON you got from server?

Comment: learn the debugger and see what the server is sending, as already mentioned.....

Comment: JSONParser, i added the of the class up

Comment: What is the json, you get from server?

Comment: add the json to ur post

Comment: the JSON is in the end of the post

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post the text itself so we can copy-paste and try ourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You web service is not creating valid JSON. A JSON string can only start with `{` or `[`. Yours starts with the String `"Array"`.

You can read about the JSON format in its Wikipedia entry [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "Array" at the begining, the json is bad formed